# How to query data from different collections and sort by date?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I stumbled upon problem that my search results are of a mixed data, which is located in different collections (posts/venues/etc), currently Im doing separate requests to retrieve this data, but its obviously sorted among its types (posts array, venues array)
How can I query multiple collections (posts/venues) and sort them by date/any other parameter (via mongoose)?
or maybe there is a better solution?
Thanks

Comment: First -- add some code to show what you're doing specifically. There are quite a few good examples in the documentation. Second -- you can't query multiple collections at one time. Mongoose can do some of it on your behalf, but internally, it performs multiple queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe its not possible with Mongoose, you can in the meanwhile do something like this:

```
var async = require('async');

function getPosts(cb) {
    Post.find({"foo": "bar"}, function(err, posts) {
        cb(err, posts);
    })
}

function getVenues(cb) {
    Venue.find({"foo": "bar"}, function(err, venues) {
        cb(err, venues);
    })
}

async.parallel([getPosts, getVenues], function(err, results) {
    if(err) {
        next(err);
    }

    res.send(results.sort(function(a, b) {
        //if default sorting is not enough you can change it here
        return a.date < b.date ? -1 : a.date > b.date ? 1 : 0;
    }));
});
```

This code assumes you are inside an express route and that both `Posts` and `Venues` have a common attribute; `date`. In case you named these dates attributes differently you would have to improve the sort algorithm.